# How to access default route params defined in createStackNavigator from screen component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm looking at the following example on react-navigation api docs:

```
const Store = createStackNavigator({
  Playstation: { screen: ProductScreen, params: { product: 'Playstation' } },
  Xbox: { screen: ProductScreen, params: { product: 'Xbox' } },
});
```

I have a similar implementation, and I am unable to access the product param within my `ProductScreen` component.

That is always null when calling `this.props.navigation.getParam('product')` and it's otherwise not found on `this.props` anywhere.

How should one access those params from the screen component? Should this be working as I intend, or am I misunderstanding its use?

Comment: Did you try the `this.props.navigation.state.params`? Also, `this.props.navigation.getParam` takes 2 parameters, the first is the key and the second is the default value to return in case of no value found.

Comment: yes, I did. I logged out all the props. Nothing in navigation state.

Comment: This is entirely based on another error. I'm not using the stack navigator I thought I was!